# Debezium stops after initial sync

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium

The initial sync works as expected but then the connector just stops and does not care about further table changes. There are no errors thrown and the connector is still marked as active and running.

Database: Amazon Postgres v10.7

Debezium config:

```
  "name": "postgres_cdc",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "database.hostname": "...",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "...",
    "database.password": "...",
    "database.dbname": "...",
    "database.server.name": "...",
    "table.whitelist": "public.table1,public.table2,public.table3",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "transforms": "unwrap, route, extractId",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": false,
    "transforms.route.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.route.regex": "[^.]+\\.[^.]+\\.(.+)",
    "transforms.route.replacement": "postgres_$1",
    "transforms.extractId.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "transforms.extractId.field": "id"
  }
}
```

Any thoughts about what the problem could be?

*Edit:*

Log-Errors:

```
ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=postgres_cdc-0} Failed to flush, timed out while waiting for producer to flush outstanding 75687 messages (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=postgres_cdc-0} Failed to commit offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter)
```

Comment: COuld you please add further infomration like the content of the log? If you could gather log also on DEBUG level it would be even helpful.
As a side question - what is your motivation to use `StringConverter` for key?
Thanks

Comment: I've added the errors from the log.

Referring to your question about the string converter: what exactly do you mean? Is it unnecessary or uncommon?

Comment: The error you provide from the log can be fixed using https://debezium.io/documentation/faq/#how_to_solve_offset_flush_timeouts
But that's not root cause of the issue that you have. Could you please check the configuration of POstgreSQL publication used by Debezium?

Answer (score 1):

You can diagnose whether it's a Postgres issue or a connector issue by running these four commands on Postgres, assuming logical replication is enabled:

```
select * from pg_create_logical_replication_slot('test', 'test_decoding', false, false);

create table planet (name text);

insert into planet (name) values ('earth');

select * from pg_logical_slot_peek_changes('test', null, null);
```

If it comes back with transaction data:

```
    lsn    | xid  |                      data
-----------+------+-------------------------------------------------
 0/4021CD0 | 8734 | BEGIN 8734
 0/4021CD0 | 8734 | table public.planet: INSERT: name[text]:'earth'
 0/4021D40 | 8734 | COMMIT 8734
(3 rows)
```

then Postgres is fine and the issue is likely with Debezium.

If it comes back with no data:

```
 lsn | xid | data
-----+-----+------
(0 rows)
```

then you've isolated it as a Postgres issue.

In our case, we isolated the issue as a bug/discrepancy that happens only on:

1. Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL
2. when `synchronous_commit = off`.

but not on any standard PostgreSQL instance with `synchronous_commit = off`. We filed [a bug report with AWS](https://repost.aws/questions/QU_4m9WIVUQ1aC-w4v2MzC7g/bug-aurora-postgresql-does-not-perform-logical-decoding-when-synchronous-commit-off) regarding this issue.

To clean up:

```
select pg_drop_replication_slot('test');
```

---

Regarding the log message `Failed to flush` / `Failed to commit offsets`, I couldn't find any definitive answer on whether the data is intact, though [this author](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60317081/15295209) suspects that the data is fine and only performance is affected.